# Correctly Specifying JAVA_HOME on CentOS Box

Tags: linux, environment-variables, chef-infra, java-home

Using Vagrant and Chef on a CentOS 6.5 box, I have the following cookbooks:

```
chef.add_recipe "yum" 
chef.add_recipe "custom_java_cookbook" # simply installs the Oracle Java 7 RPM
chef.add_recipe "set_env_var"
```

Overall, my problem is how to correctly specify JAVA_HOME to use the Oracle Java 7 version over the yum-installed OpenJDK6.

`set_env_var` sets the following environment variables:

- M2_HOME
- GRADLE_HOME
- JAVA_HOME

Using the magic shell cookbook, I successfully set the first 2 environment variables, but not `JAVA_HOME`. However, after running `vagrant up --provision`, my `$JAVA_HOME` is set to the open-jdk6 directory.

Looking in /etc/profile.d, I have 2 shell scripts corresponding to setting `JAVA_HOME`:

```
-jdk.sh # I'm guessing it's part of the yum cookbook. {export JAVA_HOME = openjdk6}
-JAVA_HOME.sh # Chef-created script: {export JAVA_HOME = jdk7_oracle_dir}
```

How can I specify which `JAVA_HOME` environment script to use under `/etc/profile.d`?

It seems that the `jdk.sh` is winning over the `JAVA_HOME.sh` since my `JAVA_HOME` is set to the openjdk6 version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to set JAVA_HOME yourself via a custom cookbook/recipe, you should probably remove the existing jdk.sh in the same recipe.  Something like:

```
file "/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh" do
  action :delete
end
```

Would be useful to wrap that in checks to only apply when absolutely necessary (i.e., if file exists, if yum installed, if platform is what you expect, etc)

Comment: This seems pretty hacky to me. I understand you're offering a way to do it, but does it seem inelegant to you?

Comment: ha -- well you did decide to use magic_shell, didn't you?  good luck